# ReactJS, How to reload a component only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I need a logic in which I can reload a component route only once.when it load at first time. So, it can load all the js files properly.In my situation in react-modal jquery is not working when modal open.If we reload it then it works better.

```
MianComponent
-> childComponent(import jQuery file)
->Modal in childComponent
        when MainComponent reload it reload all the js file only once.but if we open the modal then jquery doesn't work,So need to reload that childComponent.How can,we reload childComponent only once or any other solution.
```

Comment: So you are saying that you want to force a re-render one time? You might be able to use `forceUpdate()` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: I tried it but the page reload again and again..

Comment: Can you post some code or even better a working example with jsfiddle or codepen?